# Bootstrap thymeleaf dynamic select list

Tags: javascript, java, spring, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I'm writing an application using spring boot + thymeleaf + bootstrap.
The application is a typical CRUD:
- the user of the application has his clients
- every customer has their devices and locations

I wonder how to implement a dynamic select list (on the device adding form).
I would like to have a list of all clients after expanding the Company list.
However, after selecting a specific customer, on the list of locations I would like to see only locations assigned to a given customer.

I have in the endpoint / customers application returning a list of all clients, I can also do endpoint / localizations receiving a client id in the requestbody and returning the list of locations.
I might as well share rest api to return these lists.

What solution do you recommend?
My guess is that you can't get it without js that I don't know.

Company 1:

[image]

Company 2:

[image]